# Check if dhcp is enabled on an interface

Tags: networking, scripts, dhcp

I'm trying to figure out if dhcp is enabled on an interface programatically and I wanted to ask if the solution I've come up with should be ok. I'm on Ubuntu Server 20.04. What I was planning on doing is using `ip r` like this.

```
ip r | awk '/default/ && /myinterface/'
```

Then I could grep it for `dhcp` or just include it in my awk and if my result is empty then dhcp is off.

Is this a reasonable approach? Any caveats with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the word "dynamic" in the address config.

```
ip -o address | grep -w dynamic
```

Newer versions of `ip` are able to provide json output, which can be parsed with a json parser. For example:

```
ip -j address | jq "."
```

(I am not an expert in json parsing, that is why I can not provide the exact json search term)

Comment: Oh man! I can't give you upvotes cause I don't have enough cred around here :) but those are great suggestions!! Thank you!